# calculate a running cumulative return from daily returns

Tags: r

Similar to this question: [R: Cumulative return, what is the correct way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784796/r-cumulative-return-what-is-the-correct-way)

But is there a way to compute what the running total be?
Ie so an input of `c(0.5, 0.3, -0.2)` would return

```
c(0.5, 0.95, 0.56)
```

I guess I could compute the running total in a for loop/lapply, but is there a more elegant way?

edit: fixed typo in the output. return calculated like this:

```
first element = first element 
second element = -1 + ((1 + 0.5) * (1 + 0.3)) = 0.95
third element = -1 + ((1 + 0.95) * (1 + -0.2)) = 0.56
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `accumulate`

```
library(purrr)
accumulate(v1, ~ ((1 + .x) * (1 + .y)) - 1)
#[1] 0.50 0.95 0.56
```

---

Or in `base R` with `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(x, y) ((1 + x) * (1 + y)) - 1, v1, accumulate = TRUE)
#[1] 0.50 0.95 0.56
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(0.5, 0.3, -0.2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is using `cumprod` to chain-link geometric returns:

```
x <- c(0.5, 0.3, -0.2)
cumprod(1+x)-1
#[1] 0.50 0.95 0.56
```